# How do I get a frozen key mold with no ice biome?

Tags: terraria-console

On my 3ds terraria I went into my dungeon and found a frozen chest,but I don't have an ice biome. The websites I have looked at do not have any information on this specific issue. I do not know how to get one andd I do not want to make another world just for this one thing. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

While I guess it's possible that your world did not generate with a snow biome, it's more likely that the top of it was covered by corruption/crimson generation and if you dig down you'll find it.

I'm unfamiliar with cheating options on the 3DS version, but if your world actually didn't generate with an ice biome, your options are to cheat, use a second world, or build your own.

To create an ice biome in your world you'll need blocks of snow which you can harvest from another world, or from the hardmode frost legion Christmas event. To access this you'd need to either wait until December, or set your 3DS date to sometime between Dec 1st and 31st. During this time enemies drop presents which can be opened for various items, including the snow globe that summons the frost legion. Once the frost legion arrives, the enemies drop snow blocks, and one of them fires snow blocks similar to an antlion firing sand blocks. You'll need at least 300 blocks of snow to create your biome, although more would be better.